# I want to know the keyword 'retry' from Apple's source code

Tags: objective-c

When I watched Apple's source code, I saw the code like this:

```
{
 retry:

    if (!result  &&  class_hash) {
        // Check ordinary classes
        mutex_lock (&classLock);
        result = (id)NXHashGet(class_hash, &query);
        mutex_unlock (&classLock);
    }
}
```

What's the method about this keyWord '`retry`'?

Answer (score 3):

Retry in this context is a label and not a keyword. at some later stage a "goto retry" will get called.